# maximum 2 digits from a number

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, integer, max

Here is my code in an 'attempt' to find the maximum 2 values from a number input by the user:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void maximum2(int a, int& max1,int& max2 ){

int temp = 0;
max2= a%10;
max1 = ((a/10)%10);

if (max2>max1) {
  temp = max1;
  max1 = max2;
  max2 = temp;}
for(; a>0; a/=10){
    if (a%10>max1)max1= a%10;
    else if (a%10<max1 && a%10>max2) max2 = a%10;
}

}
void main(){

int max1, max2, num;
cin>>num;
  maximum2(num,max1,max2);
  cout<<"max 1 = "<<max1<<" max 2 = "<<max2<<endl<<endl;
}
```

It works perfectly fine for most numbers, e.g.  e.g. 34256 except certain cases. For instance when I input 54321 it gives max1 to be 5, which is correct, but it gives max2 to be 1, which is not the desired value. Would you be kind enough to help me trace my error?

Comment: `main` must return `int`.

Comment: it still does not fix the problem.

Comment: Please reindent your code. Also, use more space will add readability to the code instead of a hard-to-read batch of things like that. And note that there's no need to calculate `a % 10` lots of times in the same loop, it's just waste the running time

Comment: @user657267 In embedded systems there's no need for main to return anything. And old C compilers as well as Visual C accepts `void main()`, no need to care about that

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc the compiler is smart enough to use a temp value instead of computing the same op over and over again, if it sees it fit.

Comment: OK I tried my best to include its readability. I am still relatively new to C++, so the only way to isolate digits that I know of is by (a%10)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Compilers will accept all sorts of things, especially if warnings are not enabled. C++ requires that `main` return `int`, end of story.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution, but perhaps a different way of looking at things:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string num;  
  std::cin >> num;  

  std::sort(num.begin(), num.end(), std::greater<>{});
    // Or std::greater<char> if your compiler doesn't support the shorter syntax

  std::cout << num[0] << ' ' << num[1] << '\n';
}
```

Obviously not much use if the user enters chars other than 0-9, although you could always parse the string with `isdigit` to remove any other chars.

Comment: interesting answer I guess. I think I should have mentioned in the OP that I am still relatively new to programming, I so do not have a knowledge of the 'algorithm' or 'sting' libraries

Answer (score 1):

Change your `for` loop to:

```
for(; a>0; a/=10){
    int r = a % 10;
    if(r > max2) max2 = r;
    if(max2 > max1) std::swap(max1, max2);
}
```

**Reason:** In your `for` loop while you compare current digit of interest with `max2` afterwards you don't compare `max2` with `max1` to check whether `max1` needs to be updated.

**Core C++ version:**

```
for(; a>0; a/=10){
    int r = a % 10;
    if(r > max2) max2 = r;
    if(max2 > max1) {
      int tmp = max2;
      max2    = max1;
      max1    = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `for` loop, you are changing **either** the value of `max1` **or** the value of `max2`. But in order for your code to work in all cases, there must be a point within the `for` loop, where you change **both** the value of `max1` **and** the value of `max2`.

Having said that, here is a fix-suggestion:

```
void maximum2(int a,int& max1,int& max2)
{
    max1 = 0;
    max2 = 0;
    for(; a>0; a/=10)
    {
        int temp = a%10;
        if (temp > max1)
        {
             max2 = max1;
             max1 = temp;
        }
        else if (temp > max2)
        {
             max2 = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is in these conditions in the function

```
if (a%10>max1)max1= a%10;
else if (a%10<max1 && a%10>max2) max2 = a%10;
```

For such numbers as 54321 the else statement will be executed never because any next digit is greater than max1 except the first two digits. But even for the first two digits the else statement will be executed never.

Take into account that the value of an argument can be a negative number.

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <utility>

//...

std::pair<int, int> maximum2( int x, unsigned int base = 10 )
{
   std::pair<int, int> max( 0, 0 );

   unsigned int z = std::abs( x );

   do
   {
      unsigned int digit = z % base;

      if ( max.first < digit )
      {
         max.second = max.first;
         max.first = digit;
      }
      else if ( max.second < digit )
      {
         max.second = digit;
      }
   } while ( z /= base );

   return max;
}
```